Разметка текста в двух блоках

Привет народ. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать что бы текст выглядел как на картинке выше? А именно что бы все параграфы были на одном уровне не зависимо от паддингов
.info__text-column{
    display: flex;
}

.column__left{
    padding-right: 120px;
}

.info__text p{
    max-width: 480px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

У меня выходит только так. Я только учусь, но не смог найти информацию как это дело растянуть


каждый абзац  в отдельный  параграф  <p></p>  и задай параграфу одну высоту

Вот тут ответ на ваш вопрос https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8

Спасибо большое. Очень помогли!

Html-разметку Вы не привели, но судя по css, Вы зачем-то делаете две колонки (а в левой ещё и паддинг справа). На самом деле все абзацы надо упаковать в одну обёртку, задать ей display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between, а абзацам - ширину меньше 50%:


.about__box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.about__text {
  width: 46%;
}
<div class="about__box">
  <p class="about__text">
    Канарские острова не случайно называют европейскими Гавайями – это идеальное место для поклонников серфинга: стабильный
    теплый ветер круглый год, песчаные пляжи, километры нетронутых просторов и прозрачное море. А настоящей Меккой для
    серфингистов становится Фуэртевентура – второй по величине остров архипелага.
  </p>
  <p class="about__text">
    Пока что вы только хотите понять, что такое серфинг, или уже испытали всю прелесть катания на волнах, но желаете поднять
    свой уровень? Наша школа серфинга сможет предложить обучение для любого уровня подготовки.

  </p>
  <p class="about__text">
    Именно здесь лучшее в Испании место, в котором можно пройти обучение серфингу. Кроме того, что зимой и осенью сюда
    приходят огромные атлантические волны, Фуэртевентура может похвастать и множеством мелководных спокойных лагун, отлично
    подходящих для обучения начинающих серфингистов.
  </p>
  <p class="about__text">
    Четыре часа увлекательных занятий в день помогут вам уверенно покорять волны, почувствовать себя настоящим серфингистом.
  </p>
  <p class="about__text">
    Серфинг на Канарских островах доступен круглый год – и волны, и подходящая погода здесь есть всегда. Причем волну,
    подходящую по уровню, сможет найти и настоящий профи, и новичок. Не случайно считается, что именно это место лучше всего
    подойдет для обучения здесь возможно без сложностей переходить на новый уровень.
  </p>
  <p class="about__text">
    Основные достоинства нашей русской школы – высокое качество преподавания и организации занятий, безопасность (все наши
    клиенты застрахованы в компании Allianz), отличный инвентарь и экипировка (предоставляется на весь курс обучения), в том
    числе мягкие безопасные доски для начинающих.
  </p>
  <p class="about__text">
    Перечисляя достоинства, нельзя обойти и то, что пляжи Фуэртевентуры самые протяженные на Канарах. В итоге невозможно
    представить их переполненных туристами. Вы столкнетесь только с теми, кого,как и вас, будет интересовать одна цель –
    обучение серфингу.
  </p>
  <p class="about__text">
    Сначала мы определяем уровень катания и физической подготовки и только потом составляем программу подготовки. И можем
    заверить, что после того, как закончится обучение, вы не только получите массу великолепных ощущений, но и это уровень
    поднимется на новую ступень.
  </p>
</div>




Да , я сделал две колонки. И вот с помощью подсказки выше от Air, задал параграфу определенную высоту и вроде как даже все получилось. Ваш способ конечно интереснее. Спасибо. Но тогда как уменьшить расстояние между этими столбцами? Просто по макету там оно меньше.

@АртемНикитин, задавать определённую высоту параграфам - не самая хорошая идея в плане адаптивности сайта под разные размеры экрана: в какой-то момент текст, где его много, начнёт вылезать за пределы этой высоты. Лучше использовать возможности флекс-контейнера. Что касается расстояния между столбцами - я задал ширину параграфам 46%, но можно ведь задать и 48%, и даже 49%. Главное, меньше 50%, чтобы расстояние сохранялось, и текст не слипался.

Понял, спасибо за помощь!

Сделайте через грид и не мучайтесь.

@OliverPatterson, а в чём здесь мучение? Грид ничего дополнительного в данном случае не даст

display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; gap: 30px; - и больше ничего не нужно. Не нужно width: 48%.

@OliverPatterson, а gap: 30px? почему 30?

@Danila у автора было padding-bottom: 30px, конечно горизонтальный отступ будет другим, но уже другой вопрос.
